# Stuck snapchat app

Tags: ios-appstore

I'm not allowed to have a snapchat due to very overprotective parents. I download and delete the app multiple times a day so that I won't get caught. Today I deleted it and tried to get it back a few hours later but it didn't work. I proceeded to try to redownload the app multiple times but it still wouldn't work. I click on the little iCloud button and it acts like it's going to load but then the iCloud button just pops up again:/ I've tried restarting my phone multiple times, resetting all my settings, and signing out of my apple/iTunes account. If you have any ideas please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue with the App Store affecting some apps, including Snapchat and Netflix, but select other apps as well. I couldn't update Snapchat and I also can't redownload it. Hopefully the problem is fixed soon. But it's not just you.